# DataSet Query defaulting to string instead of DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, parameters

I am having a problem with the .Net C# building my queries with parameters of type string instead of DateTime.

The database column is type (SQL) 'date'.

I can manually change the "string RptDate" to "DateTime RptDate" and it works perfectly, but as soon as I make changes to the Dataset it regenerates the Designer code, overwriting my changes.

Any ideas on how to force the parameter to be of a specific type?

```
// this is system generated code from the "Dataset.Designer.cs" file
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
        public virtual prDataSet.DetailedRow1DataTable GetDataByUserDate(string RptDate, string UserID) { // this first parameter should be DateTime
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
            if ((RptDate == null)) {
                throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("RptDate");
            }
            else {
                // This next line should cast the value as DateTime
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(RptDate));
            }
            if ((UserID == null)) {
                throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("UserID");
            }
            else {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(UserID));
            }
            prDataSet.DetailedRow1DataTable dataTable = new prDataSet.DetailedRow1DataTable();
            this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
```

SQL query code:

```
SELECT 
    id, category, rpt_date, user_id, details, last_modified
FROM         
    DetailedRow
WHERE     
    (rpt_date = @RptDate) AND (user_id LIKE @UserID)
```

Database create code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DetailedRow]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(100000,1) NOT NULL,
    [category] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rpt_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [details] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [last_modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DetailedRow] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DetailedRow] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_DetailedRow_last_modified]  
      DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [last_modified]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I'd check is the GUI version of the DataSet designer.   Just to make sure that the rpt_date field in the DataTable is DateTime

Comment: The data type for the rpt_date column in the DataTable in the designer is System.DateTime.

Comment: I was able to change the data type of the parameter in the parameters collection of the query. I'll have to wait till I add another query to see if it reverts back but for now it seems to have fixed it.